# Tengo un erro usando el comando mesh, el error es at 80 X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex. en matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo que graficar esta funcion, pero me da error.
Este es el codigo

```
  >> u=linspace(-2,2,200);
  >> v=linspace(-4,4,200);
  >> [x,y]=meshgrid(u,v);
  >> z=sqrt(16-4.*x.^2-y.^2);
  >> mesh(x,y,z)

  ??? Error using ==> mesh at 80
  X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Porque tiene el tag de c++?

Comment: Lo siento no me di cuenta, de eso !!

Comment: Como quito el tag de c++

Comment: Debido a los intervalos de `x` y `y` que tienes, lo que está dentro de la raíz cuadrada da números negativos, y la raíz cuadrada de números negativos generan números complejos; si te sirve, puedes usar `mesh(x, y, real(z));`

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar. ahora si me grafica